# ¿Cómo convierto "ddmmyyyy" en formato fecha en R?

Tags: r, date, formato

Tengo un archivo txt que contiene información de fecha en dos de sus columnas y se vé así:

File1

```
ID   fecha1   fecha2   x1  x2   x3   x4
6270 26012009 28022009 400 6.37 6.65 1036
6570 16012009 31032009 400 4.63 6.28 519
4270 06012009 27042009 380 5.43 6.32 206
7270 05122009 17012010 500 6.47 5.04 170
9270 03122009 16022010 400 0    0    0
3270 09122009 16032010 420 NA   NA   NA
6270 06122009 13042010 260 NA   NA   NA
```

Quiero convertir el formato de las fechas a `26/01/2009`, `28/02/2009`, `16/01/2009` etc. Al hacer un str de mi fichero de datos, me doy cuenta que las columnas de fecha están como int, por lo que he intentado los siguientes comandos sin éxito

```
File1$fecha1<-as.Date(as.character(File1$fecha2), format="%d/%m/%Y")
File1$fecha1<-as.Date(as.character(File1$fecha2), "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Al ejecutarlos e ir a mirar mi File 1, las columnas fecha 1 están como NA. Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el problema de base es la importación de datos, según dices, en el archivo tienes valores de fecha como el siguiente: `06012009` claramente es la fecha `06/01/2009`, pero mencionas que luego de importar las fechas pasan a ser columnas numéricas, entonces: ¿Que número es la cadena `"06012009"`? se trata del `6012009` (se descarta obviamente el 0 a izquierda) y ¿qué ocurre cuando lo quieres transformar en una fecha?

```
> as.character(6012009)
[1] "6012009"
> as.Date(as.character(6012009), format="%d/%m/%Y")
[1] NA
```

Claramente no se puede convertir, por un lado el formato no coincide (en la columna no tenemos barras), pero aún resolviendo esto, está el problema de las fechas cuyos días tienen un solo dígito.

#### Importar el archivo e indicar el tipo de columna

```
df <- read.table(text="ID   fecha1   fecha2   x1  x2   x3   x4
           6270 26012009 28022009 400 6.37 6.65 1036
           6570 16012009 31032009 400 4.63 6.28 519
           4270 06012009 27042009 380 5.43 6.32 206
           7270 05122009 17012010 500 6.47 5.04 170
           9270 03122009 16022010 400 0    0    0
           3270 09122009 16032010 420 NA   NA   NA
           6270 06122009 13042010 260 NA   NA   NA", 
                 header=T, 
                 colClasses=c("numeric", "character", "character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))
as.Date(df$fecha1, format="%d%m%Y")

[1] "2009-01-26" "2009-01-16" "2009-01-06" "2009-12-05" "2009-12-03" "2009-12-09" "2009-12-06"
```

si usas `read.table()` puedes especificar el tipo de dato de cada columna pasandole un vector de tipos mediante el parámetro `colClasses`. Nota: para importar un archivo debes pasarle el nombre al parámetro `file` en vez de a  `text`.

#### agregar un `0` cuando se necesite

Esta es una solución sobre los datos ya importados como numéricos, te recomiendo igual que uses la propuesta anterior ya que ataca realmente al problema, este es simplemente un paliativo

```
as.Date(ifelse(nchar(as.character(df$fecha1))==7, 
           paste0('0', as.character(df$fecha1)), 
           as.character(df$fecha1)
           ), 
    format="%d%m%Y")

[1] "2009-01-26" "2009-01-16" "2009-01-06" "2009-12-05" "2009-12-03" "2009-12-09" "2009-12-06"
```

Comment: Genial Patricio, ahora funciona siguiendo tus indicaciones. Intenté también usando el paquete LUBRIDATE e indicando df[,2]<-dmy(df[,2]) y también me solucionó el problema.