# Convertir cadena de números a fecha

Tags: r, datetime, data

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, lo que pasa es que al momento de leer una base xlsx en r, los formatos de fecha me los lee así

```
45299
```

¿Alguien sabrá una sentencia para convertirlo a fecha?

Comment: Hola Hugo, fijate si [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170951/c%C3%B3mo-convierto-ddmmyyyy-en-formato-fecha-en-r) hay algo que te sirva.

Comment: @Marce si consideras que puede ser duplicado reportalo. Si no lo es y la pregunta está bien, la puede reabrir.

Comment: @Mateo, no, para nada, y no entiendo a que te refieres con reabrir.

Comment: @Marce las preguntas que son cerradas pueden ser reabiertas. Se le quita el cartel de que está cerradas y vuelven a recibir respuestas.

Comment: @Mateo, perdón pero estoy absolutamente despistado, cual es la pregunta cerrada?

Comment: @Marce estoy hablando de el hipotético caso en que esta pregunta hubiese sido cerrada por duplicado.

Comment: @Mateo, ahh, perdón por mi torpeza, ahora te entendí. gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R te esta leyendo la fecha como el numero de días trascurridos desde el origen de Excel. Puedes transformarla a la clase `Date` de R usando el siguiente código

```
as.Date(45299, origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "2024-01-08"
```

Para corregir tu data.frame puedes usar

```
df$fecha<-as.Date(df$fecha, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Es difícil saber como se origino el problema con los detalles que compartes, trata de editar tu pregunta y agregar la función de R con que estas leyendo el archivo excel, así como una pequeña muestra de tus datos.

**openxlsx**

En el caso que uses la función `read.xlsx` del paquete `openxlsx` basta con definir el parámetro `detectDates = T`. En seguida un ejemplo de como podrías usarlo

```
library(openxlsx)
read.xlsx("Libro1.xlsx",detectDates = T)
```

**readxl**

Si usas el paquete `readxl` y su función `read_xlsx` no deberías tener este problema

```
library(readxl)    
read_xlsx("Libro1.xlsx")
```